# Error when I try to create index in elastic search from logstash

Tags: indexing, logstash

Hi Im getting the following error when I try to create index in ElasticSearch from logstash:

*[Converge PipelineAction::Create] agent - Failed to execute action 
{:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, 
:exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, input, filter, output at 
line 1, column 1 (byte 1)"*

Can you tell me if I got something wrong in my .conf file

```
iput {
    file {
    path => "/opt/sis-host/process/uptime_test*"
#        start_position => "beginning"
        ignore_older => 0
    }
}*emphasized text*

 filter {
     grok {
       match => { "message" => "%{DATA:hora} %{DATA:fecha} %{DATA:status} %{DATA:server} % 
 {INT:segundos}" }
     }
     date {
       match => ["horayfecha", "HH:mm:ss MM/dd/YYYY" ]
       target => "@timestamp"
     }
 }

 output {
       elasticsearch {
           hosts => ["host:9200"]
           index => "uptime_test-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
       }
       stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration file should start with input and not "iput"

```
input {  # not iput
    file {
    path => "/opt/sis-host/process/uptime_test*"
#        start_position => "beginning"
        ignore_older => 0
    }
}

 filter {
     grok {
       match => { "message" => "%{DATA:hora} %{DATA:fecha} %{DATA:status} %{DATA:server} % 
 {INT:segundos}" }
     }
     date {
       match => ["horayfecha", "HH:mm:ss MM/dd/YYYY" ]
       target => "@timestamp"
     }
 }

 output {
       elasticsearch {
           hosts => ["host:9200"]
           index => "uptime_test-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
       }
       stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```